# Asignar valor a texbox con atributo type="date"

Tags: html5, date, textbox

Tengo un textbox de la siguiente manera

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TXT_FechaNacimiento" runat="server" type="date"></asp:TextBox>
```

hasta este punto esta bien ya que me muestra el calendario de manera correcta, pero si quiero asignar un valor desde el código fuente este no lo muestra.

```
Me.TXT_FechaNacimiento.Text = 
Format(CDate(ARR_Resultado(0).GL_STR_FechaNacimiento), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

no asigna el valor que le estoy asignando, deja el campo en blanco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿alguna sugerencia de que poder hacer en este caso?

Comment: Prueba a asignar la fecha en formato 'yyyy-mm-dd' a ver si eso funciona.

Comment: fijate que no me funciona ya lo coloque desde el codigo con ese formato pero igual sigue dejando el dd/mm/aaaa mas no la fecha que le estoy enviando

Comment: Hola @JoseRamos . Has intentado con el atributo placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy". Te quedaría así: <asp:TextBox ID="TXT_FechaNacimiento" runat="server" type="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: gracias, fijate que no. incluso no respeta colocarle el mm/dd/yyyy con el placeholder. igual sigue sin mostrar lo que le he asignado desde codigo

Answer (score 0):

ya logre solucionarlo, al momento el código quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TXT_FechaNacimiento" runat="server"                                                                                          onfocus="(this.type='date')" onfocusout="(this.type='text')"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

del lado del codigo fuente queda de la siguiente manera:

```
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-MX")
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("es-MX")
    If Me.TXT_FechaNacimiento.Text <> "" Then
        Me.TXT_FechaNacimiento.Text = CDate(Me.TXT_FechaNacimiento.Text).Date.Date
    End If
    Me.UPL_DatosPersonales.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta solución funciona sin  tener que hacerle trampas al control. Es cuestión de formato.

```
Dim fecha As Date = Date.Today ' O cualquier otra fecha que quieras asignar
txtFnac.Text = fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```